# Получить номер строки после сортировки

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

У меня есть таблица

[image: initial table]

Я ее отсортировал

[image: sorted]

Получил такую таблицу

[image: I received such a table]

Но как я могу получить порядковый номер строки (3), где user_id равен 496171855 ? В одно действие sqlite

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber FROM ratings WHERE ...
```

http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/